# Why PeekMessage doesn't call keyboard hook proc on message posted by PostMessage?

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I have an app that handle keyboard input via keyboard hooks. It sets the hook by `SetWindowsHookEx`(`WH_KEYBOARD`,...).

When `PeekMessage` in message processing loop receives usual `WM_KEYUP` and `WM_KEYDOWN` messages from real hardware keyboard, it calls callback and all is fine, but it completely ignores messages sent by `PostThreadMessage` (and any other messaging function). It just doesn't call hook procedure!

There is piece of terrible code (mostly auto-generated by Visual Studio) below to illustrate that behavior. There is the window with message-processing loop and the thread, sending `WM_KEYDOWN` messages every 1 second. All calls of keyboard callback writes log records to the console window, and I can see them, when I press key on my keyboard, but there are no records for messages sent by second thread!

I cannot change main application implementation. In many reasons it should work via keyboard hooks. But how can I make `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` handle my keyboard messages as it handles messages from hardware keyboard? Great thanks for any help, I've spent whole week for that problem!

I've tested it on Windows 8.1 64-bit with 32-bit application.

Here is the code:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

HINSTANCE hInst;                                
TCHAR *szTitle = TEXT("Title");                 
TCHAR *szWindowClass = TEXT("HookedWindowClass");       

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardCallback(
    _In_  int code,
    _In_  WPARAM wParam,
    _In_  LPARAM lParam
    )
{
    wcout << L"KeyboardCallback " << endl; 
    MSG *msg = (MSG*)lParam;
    wcout << L"KBHOOK " << code << L" wParam " << hex << wParam << L" lParam " << lParam << dec << endl; 
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL,code,wParam,lParam);
}


ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


DWORD mainThreadId = 0 ;
HWND window = 0;

DWORD threadFn(void*)
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(!PostThreadMessage(mainThreadId,WM_KEYDOWN,0xd,0x1c0001))
        {
            cout << "Error posting message to " << hex << mainThreadId << " error " << GetLastError() << endl; 
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       _In_ LPSTR    lpCmdLine,
                       _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);


    MSG msg;

    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }



    AllocConsole();

    wfstream console_out("CONOUT$");
    wcout.rdbuf(console_out.rdbuf());


    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD,KeyboardCallback,GetModuleHandle(NULL),GetCurrentThreadId());


    mainThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

    CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadFn,NULL,0,NULL);



    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {


        switch (msg.message)
        {

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            wcout << L"WM_KEYDOWN" << L" wParam " << hex << msg.wParam << L" lParam " << msg.lParam << dec << endl; 
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}


ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}


BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;

    hInst = hInstance; 

    hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    window = hWnd;
    return TRUE;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_QUIT:
        ExitProcess(0);
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By design, PeekMessage has nothing to do with keyboard hooks.  A WH_KEYBOARD hook callback is only invoked for keyboard input received from the device driver or SendInput() input.  If you want to spy on posted messages as well then use WH_GETMESSAGE.

Comment: Well, I see PeekMessage on the call stack of KeyboardProc under debugger, when it handles keyboard messages. I don't want to spy on input, I want to send input messages to app that already written and can't be changed. Unfortunately, I cannot use SendInput as it affects whole system, whereas I need to send different input to different windows at the same time. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You will also find may other functions in the stack. That doesn't imply that they are all responsible for calling keyboard hook functions. Only one of them is. You may have picked the wrong one ...